# Does JBOSS EAP 7.0 requires JDK to support JSP files?

Tags: java, jsp, jboss7.x

I need clarification, does jboss eap 7.0 requires jdk or it works fine with jre . Because we are moving to openjdk 8. since server provided to us have only openjdk 8 
 jre version. 
Tomcat need jdk to process jsp files, similarly does JBOSS EAP 7.0 requires jdk to support jsp?

Comment: "Since openjdk 8 provides only jre.", that's not true.

Comment: @Kayaman openjdk have two versions java-1.8.0-openjdk (provide only jre) & java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel (provides jdk)

Comment: So why did you say "openjdk 8 provides only jre"? Nothing has changed, the JDK and JRE have been available separately ~always.

Comment: When you look at the [Life Cycle of a JSP page](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html), the first step is "Translation and **Compilation**" - also yes, you need JDK.

Comment: @Kayaman corrected , thanks